# Do VS2010's new "thread monitor/visualizer" features support CLR 2.0?

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visualization, monitor

In .NET Rocks episode #525, they talk about monitors/visualizers new to VS2010 that help you understand what your multi-threaded software is actually doing at runtime (where it's locking, etc).

Does that (or related) feature give any new visibility to the behavior of multi-threaded apps running in version 2.0 of the .NET CLR?

**EDIT**: Show audio and transcript: [Stephen Toub on .NET 4.0 Concurrency Features](http://dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=525)